# Chip component is crashing, gives error 'fail to instantiate class'

Tags: android-studio, materialize

I'm trying to insert a chip into my project but I got the message: Fail to instantiate one or more classes. Look below to more details.

```
<com.robertlevonyan.views.chip.Chip
    android:id="@+id/chip"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Basic test" />
```

I've tried with two versions, 1.2.4 and 2.0.3 (latest), but neither worked. I got this message on my Issues Message:
***Failed to instantiate one or more classes.***

This did not allow me to insert a chip into my project.

#### What did I try?

I tried cleaning the cache, installing another version, and restarting Android Studio IDE but they did not work.
I tried with [robertlevonyan/materialChipView](https://github.com/robertlevonyan/materialChipView) and [Materialize Chip](https://material.io/develop/android/components/chip/)

#### Exception

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/robertlevonyan/views/chip/R$styleable at com.robertlevonyan.views.chip.Chip.initTypedArray(Chip.kt:113) at com.robertlevonyan.views.chip.Chip.<init>(Chip.kt:104) at com.robertlevonyan.views.chip.Chip.<init>(Chip.kt:102) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:403) at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadClass(ViewLoader.java:186) at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:144) at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadView(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:309) at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:418) at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:429) at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:333) at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:863) at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:837) at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:394) at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:323) at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:394) at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:200) at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:572) at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$5(RenderTask.java:698) at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1590) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)`

Thanks.

Edit: I tried to create my own drawable chip but I need to change the color dynamically so I really need to use this 3rd libs.

Comment: you don't need to use a third party library just for changing the color dynamically. You can just change the background of the chip dynamically by setting the background resource file.

Comment: I don't know but I run the project and the issue with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError` is gone. I try with a drawable as well and works! Thanks I really appreciate your help.